# Напишите приложение для получения минимального целого числа из списка. Значения списка вводятся череди пропуска в одной строке

Tags: python, list

Кол:

```py
s = [87, 6, 25, 7, 105, 23, 56]
for i in range(0,7):
  if s[i] < s[i+1]:
    print(s[i])
```

Результат:

```
6
7
23
```

ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>  
    if s[i]<s[i+1]:  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Но должно вывести 1 минимальное число

Comment: список имеет метод `min`. То есть код будет `print(min(s))`

Comment: должно быть так print(min(s[i]))?

Comment: вы к списку применяте данный метод, а не к отдельным его членам. Перебор `for` вообще не нужен в этом случае

Answer (score 0):

Какие то типовые задачи пошли

коротко и просто, без `for`

```py
s = [87, 6, 25, 7, 105, 23, 56]
print(min(s))
```

Если уж очень хочется перебирать весь список, то можно вот так

```py
s = [87, 6, 25, 7, 105, 23, 56]
minimum = None
for i in s:
    if minimum == None or i < minimum:
        minimum = i

print(minimum)
```

ok, ok=)
Или так

```py
s = [87, 6, 25, 7, 105, 23, 56]
minimum = s[0]
for i in s:
    if i < minimum:
        minimum = i

print(minimum)
```

Comment: минимум можно сразу приравнять первому элементу и избавиться тем самым от сравнения minimum == None

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, даже без указанной ошибки этот код выведет не одно минимальное число, а все числа, которые меньше следующего в списке.

А во-вторых, нумерация элементов начинается с нуля, последний элемент в вашем списке имеет индекс 6. И когда вы обращаетесь к элементу номер 7 (`[i+1]` в последней итерации), то и получаете эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

range(0,7) диапазон из 7 значений, в последней итерации цикла s[i] < s[i+1] попытка обратиться к 8 значению

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).